# How the weak convergence is related with trivial topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I hope my question is not going to be silly, but I am really confused, and will appreciate any help.

1. How the weak convergence is related with trivial topology?
2. Weak convergence and pseudo-metric space. 
   As far as i know : "Pseudo-metric space is a generalised space where the distance between 2 distinct points can be zero",  but how it is connected with weak convergence, I am not getting.
3. The Baire category theorem states, that a non-empty complete metric space can not be represented as the union of countable family of nowhere dense subsets. What does it have with weak convergence?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As these topics are not very much related, maybe you can tell us why do you think they are?

Comment: I don't know, I am really confused. I am reading that "In mathematics, weak convergence in a Hilbert space is convergence of a sequence of points in the weak topology". Moreover, "In mathematics, weak topology is an alternative term for initial topology. The term is most commonly used for the initial topology of a topological vector space (such as a normed vector space) with respect to its continuous dual." May be it is nice to use it to analyse the space, since this initial(trivial. weak) topology is the smallest topology on the space or...:(

Comment: The Baire category theorem states, that a non-empty complete metric space can not be represented as the union of countable family of nowhere dense subsets. What does it have with weak convergence?  Weak topology admits only the empty set and the whole space as open sets. If so, then the space with weak topology does not belong to Baire space, which is complete metric space, and in complete metric space every sequence converges, in the the space with weak topology the sequence converges weakly,because the closure of any subset is not compact, so  any sequence there we call weakly seq/ly compact

Comment: "what does it have with pseudo-metric space?" Pseudo-metric space is the space where the distance between two distinct points may be zero, so, as far as we know... the trivial topology is NOT metrizable,because all points of the space are "lumped together" and can not be distiguished by topological means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mess up things.

The trivial topology (only the empty set and the entire space are open) is pseudometrizable by $d(x,y)=0$ for $x,y$. However, it is not metrizable, as it is not Hausdorff (as long as the space has at least 2 elements).

The weak topology is an initial topology, but it is in most cases not the trivial topology. Take a normed space $X$, then you may know that the continuous dual $X^\star$ is a normed space too and by the Hahn-Banach theorem, for each $x\in X$ there is an $x^\star\in X\star$ with $x^\star(x)\neq 0$. Now the weak topology on $X$ is the initial topology of $X^\star$, i.e. the coarsest topology that all $x^\star\in X^\star$ remain continuous. And this topology contains is Hausdorff and contains many more open sets than the trivial topology.